# Security running DOSBox on MacOS?

Tags: security

General security question. Are there security concerns running DOSBox natively on MacOS? I'm not sure if Apps are run inside some user jail that prevents the app from modifying user data outside the application or other MacOS files.

I've been running DOSBox inside a VirtualBox Debian VM, basically because I have slightly higher trust in VirtualBox packaging than DOSBox. Unfortunately, sound and mouse movement is choppy, which makes me consider running DOSBox natively on MacOS. I think about Keychain access to my accounts and if DOSBox presents a security concern. Note, I run few few open source products on MacOS natively, mostly inside Linux VM instances for this reason.

Comment: What is your concern here? DOSBox (the software) having "hidden" functionality accessing and copying your data on macOS side, or DOS applications running *within* DOSBox using "hidden" functionality within DOSBox to do this?

Comment: My concern is on the MacOS side.  Hidden scripts, etc... trojans installed with DOSBox.  I'm not sure what MacOS has in defense to this.

Comment: Some people consider open source software to be inherently more secure than closed source.  DOSBox would be subject to the same restrictions and checks as other software. My concerns would be about how old DOSBox is. Have you looked at DOSBox-X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any application you install and run can do anything you have the rights to (with some limits like camera access, full disk access etc which need to be specifically granted to applications). But this is valid for DOSbox as much as for VirtualBox, so the risk is there anyway.

OTOH DOSbox has been around for a while, so the chance of backdoors and hidden activities going unnoticed for so long is rather low. Unless you are a high profile target (where creating a version targeted specifically at you would have value for an attacker) I don‘t see a reason to worry.

PS: As has been mentioned in the comments, DOSBox is rather old (the latest release is over 10 years old), so you might be better of with [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com/) which is still under active development.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if MacOS did jails for a running app.